# Messages on ipod

Tags: messages, ipod

I have set up an ipod for my daughter and now all of my messages are sitting on the ipod. I have seen the instructions on how to block them from being received from now but can I delete what is already there without deleting them from my phone?

Answer (score 1):

Remove your account from that iPod and set up an account for your daughter. If she is young and underaged (14 and younger), set up family sharing and in the family sharing settings create a child account for her.

https://support.apple.com/en-ph/HT201060

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201088

https://support.apple.com/en-ph/HT201084